# $compile doesn't work inside Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

with this Angular directive every time my model changes, new HTML item appended to the page:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,

        scope:{
            arrayItem: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function ($scope, ele, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch( 'ngModel' , function(){
                ele.html('<div ng-click="sendLike({{arrayItem.data.timeline_content}})" class="timeline-item"> Hello {{arrayItem2.data.timeline_content}} </div>');
                $compile(ele.contents())($scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And this is HTML view:

```
<hello-world ng-repeat="arrayItem in arr" ng-model="arrayItem"></hello-world>
```

But ng-click inside dynamically generated HTML doesn't work. actually recompiling of this new added section does not works.

**UPDATE:**

this is what i want to achieve:
[image]

in fact i want to create a chat Application. messages stored inside an Array and i have to bind that array to the HTML view. if i click on every message, i need to an alert() fired inside the controller. my controller is like this:

```
app.controller("timelineCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.arr={};

    $scope.sendLike = function (id) {
        alert(id);
    };
         .
         .
         .
}
```

in the jQuery way, i simply use DOM manipulation methods and add new tags for each message but in Angular way i have to bind that array as a ng-model or something like that.

at first glance, i realize that designing a directive should be a good idea and inside module i can access to main scope and do needed thing with that directive and i expect that changes inside that directive should projected to HTML view but it fails and things like ng-click doesn't work for dynamically created tags.

Comment: this is the 3rd question you've posted in 24 hours asking how to do the same thing.  using `ele.html` isn't going to work any better than the first sample you posted yesterday using JQuery.  It's still not obvious, after 6 questions, what it is that you are actually trying to accomplish here; you keep asking XY questions without explaining the whole picture.

Comment: there is no `sendLike` in the scope you are compiling with because it is an isolated directive scope

Comment: @Claies: i have a websocket that each moment can get some messages from server. if there is a message, saves in an array. then pushes the content of that array to the HTML view. this is what i want to do from yesterday but all attempt's fails. i'm newbie to Angular and must of trouble is myself but there is no good documentation for this or good tutorial. right now i'm confused. for the goal i want and this code i wrote, do you have something to add? i can't find answer from the web

Comment: and you should at least accept answers given in the other questions.

Comment: @charlietfl: then what i have to do? in this way my code works but i need ng-click works too.

Comment: I don't understand why you have tried all these different things with directives, and JQuery, and `$compile`, when you could just simply iterate through the array with `ng-repeat` and bind the elements, unless there is something unusual about your data? in 6 questions, you've not shown your data or the HTML output you are trying to create, only thrown "I've tried this and it doesn't work either" at us.

Comment: it just feels like you're making this a lot more complex than it really needs to be, but until I can see what you expect your HTML output to be, I find it hard to try to provide an answer, and have thus far been stuck trying to get more clarification.

Comment: @Claies: you know, i just wanted to have more control and i wanted to do inside a directive or inside controller. my data is an array each item is a javascript object. what i want to be done in the end is that if any changes happened to that array, then changes projected to the html view. its like twitter timeline, each new message is a new row in HTML view, if i use ng-repeat, its not get slow if i load more new data? thats what i want and i want its be in a proper way. you say jQuery is not good approach and i change my way, right now i have trouble. sorry for interrupting

Comment: you can use one time binding if you are concerned about performance, with `ng-repeat`; in the code you posted here, you haven't really given yourself more control anyway, you are still using `ng-repeat` on the directive element, but you haven't really structured the directive in a sane manner.  I'll ask again; ***if you post an example of what you want the HTML to look like, we can work together to make a correct rendering of it.***.  without an example, we're still playing guessing games across multiple questions.

Comment: you are describing a very basic, standard process for angular, yet making it seem complex for no real reason.

Comment: ok, now let's try to put this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that you could accomplish this, with or without a directive.

Let's start without a directive; we'll assume that you have an array in the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="timelineCtrl" class="timelineframe">
  <div ng-repeat="post in timeline | orderBy:'-lineNumber'" class="post">
    <div ng-click="sendAlert(post)">
      <span class="postnumber">{{::post.lineNumber}}:</span>
      <span class="message">{{::post.message}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

whenever an object is added to $scope.timeline, it can be assigned a `lineNumber`, and we can use angular [`OrderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#!) to sort the direction in reverse `lineNumber` order (using `-`).  The `$scope.sendAlert(post)` will send the specific post to the function.  in our bindings, we use `::` to indicate that these are one time bindings, i.e. not values that need to be monitored independently of the array.  This can improve performance on large lists.

using a Directive, we can accomplish this in a very similar manner, by making a Directive that renders a specific post, and passing the post in as a property.

```
app.directive('timelinePost', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{
       post: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="postCtrl.sendAlert()">
                 <span class="postnumber">{{::postCtrl.post.lineNumber}}:</span>
                 <span class="message">{{::postCtrl.post.message}}</span>
               </div>',
    controller: 'postController',
    controllerAs: 'postCtrl',
    bindToController: true
};


app.controller("postController", function(){
  var self = this;  //save reference to this
  self.sendAlert = function(){
    //the specific post is available here as self.post, due to bindToController
  };
};

//usage in HTML:
<div ng-controller="timelineCtrl" class="timelineframe">
  <div ng-repeat="post in timeline | orderBy:'-lineNumber'" class="post">
    <timeline-post post='post'></timeline-post>
  </div>
</div>
```

you could further wrap this timeline in a directive in a similar manner, if you so desired.  Either of these will accomplish the same task, of looping through your data, ordering it so that the newest post is at the top, and updating whenever the array changes.  In the non-directive method, the `timelineCtrl` handles the `$scope.sendAlert` function; in the directive method, it is handled by the directive controller `postController`.

Please note, this is a rough draft based on what you have described and the information from various posts over the last 2 days.  I haven't created a dataset to iterate through to test thoroughly, but the logic here should get you started.

Comment: very thank's for you time. i tested both and they works. but unfortunately ng-click doesn't work either.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't make sense; can you post what the click function looks like and how you declared it in the HTML? it should work from this.

Comment: you know, ng-click inside dynamically generated HTML works like this: <div ng-click="sendAlert(post)> but not like this: <div ng-click="$scope.sendAlert(post)> , i mean with $scope prefix doesn't work. in directive mode, writing $scope or not, doesn't matter, doesn't work either.

Comment: oh that's my fault, I screwed that up, of course you wouldn't put `$scope` in the HTML, I was typing too fast.  I'll correct that.

Comment: normally I write using the ControllerAs syntax and don't use scope, let me modify the directive version slightly to show that syntax, and see if we can't correct that function call.

Comment: also putting :: cause an error fired: Error: Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression...

Comment: which version of angular are you using? the `::` was added in angular 1.3

Comment: my angular.js version was out of date and i solved it. right now everything works fine but in directive mode, first message came and pushed to HTML view, but after that next messages not. i cant findout why this happen! when i push a button, i added new item to array and then HTML automatically updates. but with last modifications, only first time i press button, HTML updates(array is fine)

Comment: it seems there is a problem with section that we bind controllers. right now, with this structure, when first item goes to array everything is OK, when second item came, doesn't append to array and replaces with first item, then next items behave normal and append to array. why second item replace with first item? logic is the same with first method, nothing changed. only when i put controller binding section, behaves like this.

Comment: I was trying to work out what you meant by this last comment; I think that might be worth a different question with the logic that you are using to modify the array.

Comment: i use standard array.push(data) to add new items. as i say, the logic is the same with first method and its working. when i add bindToController and controllerAs: 'postCtrl', this strange behavior appears. first time i press the button HTML updates normally, but next times nothing works. i log that array and it seems when second item arrives, replaces with first item for no reason.  it seems an overlapping issue or something like that